# Apache Http Server POST 400

Tags: web-services, apache, http

that's my first question here. After long research, I decided to ask for help...

So first I'll explain my scenario. I have some SOAP web services here. They're consumed by an .Net website. The .Net framework used is in version 4.0.

So my web services are configured to accept HTTP/1.0 protocol, due to .Net limitations. In spite of that, everything works fine if I access the service directly to Jboss AS(4.2.2 GA).

But, I have to make it work with Apache web server as the receptor of the request. Apache do a inverse proxy redirection to my service, so the site send requests to port 8080 (that Apache is listening) and send it to jboss that is expecting the request at port 18080.

In many tests, I confirmed that almost every service worked almost fine, sometimes they have the same failure. But one in particular don't work anyway, the request stopped at Apache with status 400 and empty value (the - after the 400) like that:

> POST /xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/MyService HTTP/1.1" 400 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Service Client Protocol 4.0.30319.296)

The other requests that are processed have this value filled. I guess is the response size.

Please consider my regards. thanks

Comment: HTTP error 400 means "bad request", a formal error . Try to look at the request with a network sniffer (such as Wireshark) and compare it with the request for a working service.

Comment: May you please add some log or error log genereted by the server?
Besides, is the server configured to also accept HTTP 1.0 or to *only* accept it? If this is the case, the line you presented explicitly state the use of HTTP 1.1. That may be the cause...

Comment: Dear Anders, thank you for your help, people from infrastructure used wirshark.. but they were not happy till this moment trying to identify the problem, the only thing that they're arguing is that jboss is returning the http 400 error, i enabled the "debug level" at jboss logging, and then i faced a problem exactly like this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/11518889/2966044

Comment: Derar Fedalto, the protocol version is still http 1.1, but not complete (there is a turn around to be compatible with .net version configured in the app), please accept my excuses for my fault..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After great efforts at my company we discovered using an Sniffer(Wireshark) that we had two problems that let us to had the situation described in this problem.

**First problem solved:** .Net platform is configured to send by default an empty request. The first attempt failed so .Net was forced to automatically send a second request with authentication. So i figured out 2 requests before the Jboss response formed an http 400 error.

**Second Problem solved:**
*After the other side solved thise previous problem configuring .Net properly, we tested again and the results were conclusive that no more requests was hitting Apache Http Server.* - So there was a strong signal that we had something blocking this specific service. With the rocks in my hand, infrastructure people started to move their asses and somehow solved the problem. Mine frustration in the end is that they didn't said nothing about the possible correction. So "suddenly" the communication was restored..

So after all we made it! but with a bitter taste of defeat. Thank you all that supported me in this problem. []s